# missing uiTableView variable

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, sdk

I have followed this tutorial http://blogs.wrox.com/article/creating-a-simple-ipad-application-table-view/ (creating a uitableview and populating it).

I want to create a button, when press the table will clear and updated.

I would do it like this ..

```
[array RemoveAllObjects];
[table reloadData];
```

However, in the tutorial there is no uiTableView variable created, so I cannot do [**table** reloadData] ... how can I fix this please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if there is no table view variable then create it like as in .h file

```
IBOutlet UITableView *tblView;
```

define property

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UITableView *tblView;
```

and synthesize in .m file

```
@synthesize tblView;
```

and connect it to IB.

Comment: I personally dislike the use of IBOutlet as a property. The IBOutlet declaration in the interface is sufficient to wire it up via interface builder AND use it within the class. I only add properties if I need the variable accessible from outside the class (in this case not needed). And for those who say with a property you can easily release the memory, this is a non-issue in my book, being more explicit with your memory handling is a good thing and reduces errors.

Answer (score 0):

As saadnib said, declare the variable in the header and wire it up via interface builder.

There is no need in this case however to add a property as I doubt you will need to access the tableview from outside of this class.

And before people say about being able to do...

`self.tblview = nil;`

to release the memory, being more explicit with your memory handling and doing...

```
 [tblview release]; 
 tbleview = nil;
```

is no bad thing and prevents errors if someone changes your 'retain' to an 'assign' etc.